# Angular ngclick add class to all siblings

Tags: angularjs

How to add class to all siblings expect the clicked one.  When I click the one I want, I want to apply class `blue` to all siblings not the one I clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/bm6kujL1/

```
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

  <div ng-repeat="item in items">

    <div class="wrap" ng-click="show =!show" ng-class="{'blue':show}">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <span ng-show="show">{{item.thing}}</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



//JS
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.editedItem = null;

  $scope.items = [{
    name: "item #1",
    thing: "thing 1"
  }, {
    name: "item #2",
    thing: "thing 2"
  }, {
    name: "item #3",
    thing: "thing 3"
  }];

  $scope.show = false;

}

var editer = angular.module('editer', []);


 //CSS
.wrap {
  background: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some small changes to your [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bm6kujL1/1/), and it works now. Basically, you only had one attribute called show for *all* items, but you needed to know for each one if it should be blue or not.

JS:

```
function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.editedItem = null;

    $scope.items = [
      { name :"item #1", thing: "thing 1", selected: false}, 
      { name :"item #2", thing: "thing 2", selected: false},
      { name :"item #3", thing: "thing 3", selected: false}
    ];

    function resetAllItems() {
        for (i in $scope.items) {
        $scope.items[i].selected = false;
      }
    }

    $scope.selectItem = function(item) {
                resetAllItems();
                item.selected = true;
    }

}
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

      <div ng-repeat="item in items">

          <div class="wrap" ng-click="selectItem(item)" ng-class="{'blue': item.selected}">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <span ng-show="item.selected" >{{item.thing}}</span>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like I have to add an extra property?

Comment: Basically yes. There are other ways also, such as finding the current element, getting all its siblings and use toggleClass on each one. For these you can use angular element [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element] which has a small subset of jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function instead and use the item `show` property.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap" ng-click="toggleShow(item)" ng-class="{'blue':item.show}">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <span ng-show="item.show">{{item.thing}}</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.items = [{
    name: "item #1",
    thing: "thing 1",
    show: false
  }, {
    name: "item #2",
    thing: "thing 2",
    show: false
  }, {
    name: "item #3",
    thing: "thing 3",
    show: false
  }];

$scope.toggleShow = function(item){
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; ++i){
        if($scope.items[i] === item){
            $scope.items[i].show = false;
            continue;
        }
        $scope.items[i].show = true;
    }
}
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bm6kujL1/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I have to add an extra property to achieve, can't be like jQuery to play with DOM only?

Comment: This is the easiest way i can think of. This isn't DOM manipulation. Angular approch is really different from jQuery. You don't directly manipulate the DOM. I don't know what you mean with "playing with DOM only". Can you precise ?